# Bing Maps Ignores Spatial Filter?

Tags: bing-maps, spatial

I have a good grasp on Bing's REST service, but, I'm **really** stumped on this one.

What I'm attempting to do is get a grocery store ($filter=5400) within a polygon located in a Florida census tract ($spatialFilter), but the results are from Massachusetts!

The URL is (I didn't supply a Bing key for obvious reasons :-)
http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/f22876ec257b474b82fe2ffcb8393150/NavteqNA/NavteqPOIs?$format=json&$top=1&$filter=EntityTypeID%20Eq%20%275400%27&$spatialFilter=intersection(POLYGON%20((-81.190439%2028.590798999999997,%20-81.193080999999992%2028.590759,%20-81.196646%2028.590698999999997,%20-81.198315999999991%2028.590671,%20-81.204715%2028.590566,%20-81.204828999999989%2028.590767,%20-81.20603899999999%2028.592836,%20-81.206306%2028.593291999999998,%20-81.206443999999991%2028.593528,%20-81.207657%2028.593486,%20-81.207929%2028.595012999999998,%20-81.20795%2028.594935,%20-81.207956%2028.594918,%20-81.208027%2028.594707,%20-81.208052999999992%2028.594631999999997,%20-81.20811599999999%2028.594452,%20-81.208207%2028.594196999999998,%20-81.208302%2028.593913999999998,%20-81.208364%2028.593733999999998,%20-81.208396999999991%2028.593638,%20-81.208413999999991%2028.593586,%20-81.208429999999993%2028.593541,%20-81.208523%2028.593269,%20-81.208565%2028.593144,%20-81.208615999999992%2028.592997,%20-81.208655999999991%2028.592879,%20-81.208713%2028.592713,%20-81.20877%2028.592523999999997,%20-81.208806%2028.592405,%20-81.208844%2028.592271999999998,%20-81.208923%2028.592004,%20-81.208951%2028.591872,%20-81.208981%2028.591738,%20-81.209%2028.591641,%20-81.209008%2028.591566999999998,%20-81.209032999999991%2028.591364,%20-81.209049999999991%2028.59114,%20-81.209049%2028.591048999999998,%20-81.209049%2028.590875999999998,%20-81.209042%2028.590608,%20-81.209042%2028.590595,%20-81.209027999999989%2028.590414,%20-81.208998999999991%2028.590194,%20-81.20894%2028.589881,%20-81.208924%2028.589817,%20-81.20886%2028.589558,%20-81.208777%2028.589311,%20-81.208744%2028.589212999999997,%20-81.208588999999989%2028.588699,%20-81.208544%2028.588565,%20-81.208461%2028.588319,%20-81.208423%2028.588206999999997,%20-81.208311%2028.587871999999997,%20-81.208274%2028.587761,%20-81.208201%2028.587557999999998,%20-81.208074%2028.587204,%20-81.207997999999989%2028.586944,%20-81.207973%2028.5868559999999&key=**<BING_KEY>**

What I'm getting back shouldn't be:

```
{
"d": {
    "results": [
        {
            "__metadata": {
                "uri": "https://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/f22876ec257b474b82fe2ffcb8393150/NavteqNA/NavteqPOIs('1001002038')"
            },
            "EntityID": "1001002038",
            "Name": "Nosso Brazil",
            "DisplayName": "Nosso Brazil",
            "AddressLine": "25 Boston Post Rd",
            "Locality": "Marlborough",
            "AdminDistrict2": "Middlesex",
            "AdminDistrict": "Massachusetts",
            "PostalCode": "01752",
            "CountryRegion": "USA",
            "Latitude": 42.35173,
            "Longitude": -71.52983,
            "Phone": "508-3032424",
            "EntityTypeID": "5400"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

From my estimation, Bing is returning the first grocery store at Bing 5400 and completely ignoring $spatialFilter parameter, can anyone determine how to return something other than what's returned? Meaning, can anyone return a grocery store within the defined polygon in Florida?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of issues with your query URL.

The first issue is that the spatial filter shouldn't start with $. As such the URL is falling back on the standard filter and grabbing the first result in the world that matches that filter value.

The second issue is that the spatial filter is not supported on the NavteqNA, NavteqEU, and FourthCoffeeSample data sources. The reason for this is that these data sources as significantly larger than the largest custom data source. Performing these types of complex queries on these large data sources would be really slow. As such this type of query has been disabled for these data sources. This is also why when looking at the Query URL samples in the documentation these data sources aren't used in the samples.

The third issues is that the Polygon string is incomplete. It appears that once a Bing Maps key is added to that URL the total length of the URL is 2083 characters which is the limit supported by browsers. This is likely why your Polygon text is cut off. A couple of tips to help prevent this, reduce the number of decimal places that are in your string. 5 decimal places has an accuracy of +/- 0.17 meters which is likely accurate enough for your application. Some of your numbers have 15 decimal places, so this is potentially 10 characters per number that you could eliminate.

If you have your well known text for the polygon already in code, you can use a simple regular expression to find and replace this. Use the following pattern:

> ([0-9]*.[0-9]{5})([0-9]*)

and replace it with

> $1

This will remove all numbers after 5 decimal places. You can further optimize the URL by removing the spaces after the comma's as they are not needed. By doing these two things you could cut the length of the URL in half.

Since the polygon is cut off the Well Known text is invalid. To be valid the polygon must end with the same coordinate that it starts with.